# iPhone text messages and iPads

Tags: apple-id, iphone, sms

My husband and I have separate Apple ID accounts.  He has gotten old deleted text messages from my iPhone appearing on his iPad. I do not own an iPad; only a Macbook Pro computer.  My son had the same issue but at the time he **did** share an Apple ID with my husband.  I, however, have a separate Apple ID and have no idea why he would be getting deleted text messages from my iPhone appearing on his iPad.  Thoughts? We are on the same Verizon account and share Wi-Fi in the same house but that is all.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are these text messages from iMessage or SMS from Verizon?

Comment: I am not sure. What is the difference between iMessage and SMS and how would this impact this situation with old text messages showing up on a different device with a different apple id? Thanks!

Comment: iMessage's are sent only from an Apple device to an Apple device.  SMS can be sent from any device to any device.  If these are SMS the chat bubble is green; if iMessage, it's blue.  If you deleted the messages they would still be visible on his side of the chat.  It's possible some of your old messages didn't go thru (network glitch) and then suddenly were sent.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by changing values under setting/messages/send receive.
For the iPhone enter the phone number then mark it with a check mark.
For the iPad enter your Apple ID.
My initial confusion stemmed from thinking that the Apple ID had to be used for both. It may have been that way long ago. I am not sure.
Good luck.

5/14/2016 Hi, your latest post says your husband has his phone number checked on his iPad. I have my Apple ID checked on my iPad. Also, I recommend deleting the old text messages as they might be giving false impressions. The original programmers are probably shocked that their strategy is being tested by families that have o many Apple devices!

Comment: Hi there. My iPhone, under setting/message/send receive  has my phone number with a check mark only. My husband's iPad has his phone number with a check mark under the same setting.  We both have separate apple id's.  Still a mystery how my deleted old texts have shown up on his iPad.

Comment: His iPad only has his phone number and Apple Id as "send and receive" under iMessage.  My iPhone only has my phone number and Apple Id as "send and receive". He continues to get old deleted text messages on his iPad from my iPhone from many months ago, which is a mystery.  Any thoughts on this, since we both have different Apple Ids?  Would it make any difference that we are on the same Verizon account?